# KIVY : cavas size in layout

Tags: canvas, kivy

I am learning KIVY from "Kivy: Interactive Applications in Python" and I was trying to integrate AnchorLayout, ScrollView and RelativeLayout as per the sample code given below.

In the code I had given below, I was trying to visualize the "RelativeLayout" within ScrollView (In anchorlayout anchor_x: 'center' and anchor_y: 'center' ) by defining a rectangle size of self.size.
Seems Rectangle is getting drawn on top of "ToolBox" which is at AnchorLayout: anchor_x: 'center' and anchor_y: 'top'. 
As per my KV canvas should be exactly between "ToolBox" and "GeneralOptions". But why this overlap.

```
#File name: comiccreator.kv
<ComicCreator>:
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'top'
        ToolBox:
            id : _tool_box
            size_hint: 1,None
            height: 20
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Label:
                text: 'Tool Box'
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
        ScrollView:
            size_hint: 1,1
            RelativeLayout:
                size_hint: 1,None
                height: root.height - _tool_box.height - _general_options.height
                canvas.before:
                    Color: 
                        rgba: 1,0,0,0.5
                    Rectangle:
                        size: self.size
                        pos: self.pos
                DrawingSpace:
                    id: drawing_space
                    Label:
                        text: 'DrawingSpace'
                        pos : 0, 50
                        size: 50, 50
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'bottom'
        GeneralOptions:
            id: _general_options
            size_hint: 1,None
            height: 20
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Label:
                text: 'General Options'
```

The python script is...

```
# File name: comiccreator.py
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

class DrawingSpace(RelativeLayout):
    pass

class ToolBox(BoxLayout):
    pass

class GeneralOptions(BoxLayout):
    pass

class ComicCreator(AnchorLayout):
    pass

class ComicCreatorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ComicCreator()

if __name__=="__main__":
    Window.size = (400, 200)
    ComicCreatorApp().run()
```

Comment: All three of your `AnchorLayouts` are the full size of your `ComicCreator`  instance, since they all are using the default `size_hint` of `(1,1)`, and the default `pos` of `(0,0)`. The `anchor_x` and `anchor_y` attributes of an `AnchorLayout` only affect where its child is positioned, not where the `AnchorLayout` is positioned.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of your `kv` that does not use `AnchorLayouts`:

```
#File name: comiccreator.kv
<ComicCreator>:
    ToolBox:
        id : _tool_box
        size_hint: 1,None
        height: 20
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'top':1}
        Label:
            text: 'Tool Box'
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: root.height - _tool_box.height - _general_options.height
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}
        y: _general_options.height
        RelativeLayout:
            size_hint: 1,None
            height: root.height - _tool_box.height - _general_options.height
            canvas.before:
                Color: 
                    rgba: 1,0,0,0.5
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            DrawingSpace:
                id: drawing_space
                Label:
                    text: 'DrawingSpace'
                    pos : 0, 50
                    size: 50, 50
    GeneralOptions:
        id: _general_options
        size_hint: 1,None
        height: 20
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'y':0}
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Label:
            text: 'General Options'
```

And I have changed `ComicCreator` to extend `RelativeLayout` instead of `AnchorLayout`:

```
class ComicCreator(RelativeLayout):
    pass
```